Show $P(X > x, Y>y, X<Y \mid Z=z, W= w) \le P(X > x, X<Y\mid Z=z, W=w)$
It is clear that $P(X > x, Y>y, X<Y)\le P(X > x, X<Y)$. Define $Z = \min(X,Y)$ and an arbitrary random variable $W$, here is my claim:
$$P(X > x, Y>y, X<Y \mid Z=z, W= w) \le P(X > x, X<Y\mid Z=z, W=w).$$
Here is what I have tried: the left hand side of the above is
\begin{align*}
P(X > x, Y>y, X<Y \mid Z=z, W= w)&= \frac{P(X > x, Y>y, X<Y, Z=z, W= w)}{P(Z=z, W= w)}
\end{align*}
And the right hand side is
\begin{align*}
P(X > x, X<Y \mid Z=z, W= w)= \frac{P(X > x, X<Y, Z=z, W= w)}{P(Z=z, W= w)}.
\end{align*}
So it's suffice to compare the two numerators $P(X > x, Y>y, X<Y, Z=z, W= w)$ and $P(X > x, X<Y, Z=z, W= w)$. Since the event in the first probability is a subset of the event in the second probability, my claim holds.
My concern: it looks too simple to be true. I believe my argument works if both $Z$ and $W$ are arbitrary random variables, but I'm not certain when $Z = \min(X,Y)$. I'm afraid I missed something important in my thinking process.
I also tried to continue thinking the event $\{X > x, Y>y, X<Y, Z=z, W= w\}$ as $$\{z > x, Y > y, X<Y, W=w\},$$ where $\{z>x\}$ is purely deterministic.
And rethink the event $\{X > x, X<Y, Z=z, W= w\}$ as $$\{z>x,X<Y, W=w\}.$$
Still, the event $\{z > x, Y > y, X<Y, W=w\}$ is a subset of $\{z>x,X<Y, W=w\}$, which supports my claim.
Is it really true?

It really is as simple as $A\subseteq B$ implies $P(A)\leq P(B)$.
